# R is giving the wrong max date

Tags: r

I am having an annoying issue in R that is not recognizing the correct date in my dataframe as the max date. I am creating a weighted average based on subtracting the date in the dataframe from the max date, so this is an annoying issue to deal with. I have tried reformatting all of the dates, this did not work.

Anything that I can try? The dates range from 1/1/2020 to 12/23/2020. But when I use max(PlayerData$Date) I am getting 3/9/2020.

Thanks

Comment: Please use `dput` to share the data for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `max()` is not working for characters. You need to transform it to date class. Here an example:

```
#Data
PlayerData <- data.frame(Date=c('3/9/2020','1/1/2020','12/23/2020'),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Your approach:

```
#OP
max(PlayerData$Date)
```

Output:

```
max(PlayerData$Date)
[1] "3/9/2020"
```

Setting as date:

```
#Date
max(as.Date(PlayerData$Date,'%m/%d/%Y'))
```

Output:

```
max(as.Date(PlayerData$Date,'%m/%d/%Y'))
[1] "2020-12-23"
```